# Return different types for same method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method that takes a list of tasks as Params & does the following

- Execute all tasks in the list
- extract results out
- Merge them

Currently I have only 2 tasks in the input list to the method. Lets call them `Task1` & `Task2` `Task1` returns an object & `Task2` returns a property with the object returned by `Task1`. So
Task1

```
Task<AcmsSettings> GetMySettings(//params);
```

Task2

```
Task<AppsPermissionSettings> GetMyPolicy(//Params)
```

AcmsSettings:

```
public class AcmsSettings
{
    //Other Props
    public AppsPermissionSettings AppsPermissionPolicy { get; set; }
}
```

Below is my Task execution method

```
private async Task<AcmsSettings> GetPoliciesFromTasks(IList<Task> taskList)
{
    TeamsAppPermissionPolicy teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE = new TeamsAppPermissionPolicy();
    try
    {
        //Execute Tasks
        await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        foreach (Task faulted in taskList.Where(s => s.IsFaulted))
        {
            Exception e = faulted.Exception?.InnerException;
            DiagnosticsContext.Logger.LogError($"Get {faulted} Task failed. ex={ex}.");
        }
    }
    var otherPolicies = taskList[0].IsFaulted ?
        new AcmsSettings() 
        : ((Task<AcmsSettings>)taskList[0]).Result;
    if (taskList.Count > 1) //Making sure we only read response if we hit AAE Backend. In which case tasklist length is 2.
    {
        teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE = taskList[1].IsFaulted ?
               new TeamsAppPermissionPolicy() : ((Task<TeamsAppPermissionPolicy>)taskList[1]).Result;
    }
    //Merge Results here
    otherPolicies.AppsPermissionPolicy = teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE.ToMTTeamsAppPermissionPolicy().ToMTPolicyDocument();
    return otherPolicies;
}
```

Now I have to run the same logic on other types say `Type1` & `Type2` which also have `AppsPermissionSettings` as sub type. They have some parameterized constructors too.

```
public class Type1
{
    //Parameterized constructor for Type1 
    public Type1(UserSettings userSettings, Permissions permissions)
    {
    }

    //Other Props
    public AppsPermissionSettings AppsPermissionPolicy { get; set; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public Type2(Properties props, Permissions permissions)
    {
    }

    //Other Props
    public AppsPermissionSettings AppsPermissionPolicy { get; set; }
}

`Type1`, `Type2` & `AcmsSettings` dont inherit from any base types.
```

I want `GetPoliciesFromTasks` to return `Type1` & `Type2` by running the same logic. I can't  overload on return type.

I am wondering if I could use generics to achieve my need, but not sure on how to call parameterized constructors of types1 & 2 in case of result is null for their tasks.
Here is the logic for creating my tasklist.

```
var taskList = new List<Task>
                {
                    _myProxy.Method1(tenantId, userPoliciesToFetch)
                };

                if (isTenantResolutionModelCustom)
                {
                    taskList.Add(GetDocFromCacheOrBackendAsync(null, userId));
                }
```

Comment: Can not you use inheritance for this?

Comment: There is no base type or common props among these classes. They are just independent models

Comment: IMHO you're thinking about the problem the wrong way around. Just because `Task.WhenAll` takes a collection, doesn't mean you should force the rest of your process to use that collection. Your process has more structure than that, and you should use that structure in a more direct way.

Comment: I'm sorry can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, my issue was not on number of tasks, I am wondering how do I refactor so I could reuse most of the code and get the functionality supporting different types like I said in my question. At this time its only 2 tasks , I could pass as 2 different parameters instead in a tasklist. I would want to support multiple types since its the same repetitive logic I need to change for diff types.

Comment: Where is your code that creates this list of tasks? IMHO each task should be responsible for processing / storing its own result, probably including the exception handler. Even if that means you need to write a one line async lambda for each task type. Then you are left with simply waiting for them all to complete. Trying to unpack a list of tasks feels like you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: just updated the question. pls check

Comment: Might want to look into [Visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern.

Comment: Please do not delete and repost questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72905749/support-multiple-return-types-for-same-logic

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to unpack list of tasks in a general way, I would recommend re-working your process so that each task can process its own result. Here's a rough idea;

```cs
AcmsSettings result = null;
TeamsAppPermissionPolicy teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE = null;

Func<Task> f1 = async (){
    try{
        result = await _myProxy.Method1(tenantId, userPoliciesToFetch);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        DiagnosticsContext.Logger.LogError( .... );
    }
};
var task = f1();
if (isTenantResolutionModelCustom){
    Func<Task> f2 = async (){
        try{
            teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE = await GetDocFromCacheOrBackendAsync(null, userId);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            DiagnosticsContext.Logger.LogError( .... );
        }
    };
    task = Task.WhenAll(task, f2());
}
await task;

result ??= new AcmsSettings();
result.AppsPermissionPolicy = (teamsAppPermissionDocFromAAE ?? new TeamsAppPermissionPolicy ())
    .ToMTTeamsAppPermissionPolicy().ToMTPolicyDocument();
```

Though you might want to move those lambda's to member or local functions, or write a general try / catch wrapper.

Comment: what if I need to repeat the same logic for diff type than `AcmsSettings` like my `Type1` & `Type2` which have parameterized constructors. How do I create refactor code that works on different type , more cleaner & maintainable is I think the crux of my question.